# R function for transforming comma-separated values in a cell into multiple rows with same row name?

Tags: r, transformation, mutate

I have a two-column dataframe in R: the first column is a broad category, and the second column contains comma-separated items within the broad category. This is what it looks like:

| Orthogroup | Sequences |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Seq1, Seq2, Seq3 |
| 1 | Seq4 |

And this is what I would like it to look like:

| Orthogroup | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Seq1 |
| 0 | Seq2 |
| 0 | Seq3 |
| 1 | Seq4 |

To be honest I'm not even really sure where to start... any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [`separate_rows()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html) from the package `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)
Orthogroup <- c(0, 1)
Sequences <- c("Seq1, Seq2, Seq3", "Seq4")
df <- data.frame(Orthogroup, Sequences)
df %>%
  separate_rows(Sequences, sep = ", ")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   Orthogroup Sequences
#>        <dbl> <chr>    
#> 1          0 Seq1     
#> 2          0 Seq2     
#> 3          0 Seq3     
#> 4          1 Seq4
```